# Get Output to a text file in a Windows Batch File which is remotely telling machines to schedule a defragmentation

Tags: batch-file

I am currently writing a Batch file (first time doing so) to remotely call machines in our network (all embedded XP) and schedule a defrag at 11:00PM (23:00).

Of course, it isn't going as planned, that is understandable. However, I would like to get the logging information that would typically be given at command prompt, such as 'disk is -% defragmented' or errors, etc. My current stage of the line that makes the call is this:

```
@FOR /F "Tokens=1" %%a IN (%List%) DO at \\%%a 23:00 defrag C: /A > C:\...\log.txt
```

NOTE: The ellipsis in between C:\ and \defraglog.txt actually have the full pathname typed. For context, %List% is a list of IP addresses.

However, defrag never even launches. According to the remote computer I am testing on, the command looks like:

```
defrag C: /A and C:\...\log.txt
```

when I look at Scheduled Tasks.

Now, when I simply use:

```
@FOR /F "Tokens=1" %%a IN (%List%) DO at \\%%a 23:00 defrag C:
```

I do get a defragmentation scheduled at 11:00PM on the remote machines, so I am assuming the issue lies in the way I am redirecting.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try adding quotes:

```
@FOR /F "Tokens=1" %%a IN (%List%) DO at \\%%a 23:00 defrag C: /A > %APPDATA%\log.txt
```

If that doesn't work, make a batch file defragXP.cmd on a network share that holds:

```
@echo off
defrag C: /A > C:\...\log.txt
```

and then schedule the batch:

```
@FOR /F "Tokens=1" %%a IN (%List%) DO at \\%%a 23:00 \\server\batches\defragXP.cmd
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I tried the quotes. It was rather strange, actually - instead of the Task Scheduler claiming I was saying: `code` defrag C: and Settings/.../log.txt Like before, it was instead saying: `code` "defrag C: > C:/.../log.txt" and would then not run, because the quotations marks were there. I haven't tried the batch on the network yet (have to get permission), but I love the idea! Even if they say no, I'm gonna have to keep that in mind.

Comment: try with %APPDATA% (that gives you the path for the user)

Comment: Thanks for the %APPDATA% tip, very useful. Strangely, and interestingly, it only seems to understand that '>' does not mean '**and**' when the destination is in quotes. `defrag C: > "%APPDATA%\log.txt`. However, when sent to the machine, the machine only sees `defrag C:`. It is very strange indeed. without the quotes, the machine sees the entire command as `defrag C: and Support\system...\log.txt`. The line the machine wants is `defrag C: > "..log.txt"`.

Comment: the redirection is applied immediately and there is no way to enclose quotes. I supect the batchfile is the only option left...

Comment: Sorry for getting back so late (weekend). I did it your way, and it seems to have solved the problem! Thanks a bunch, again!